# How to filter responses that are too long?

Tags: elasticsearch

My apologies in advance if this is question does not make sense in the elasticsearch context, but I have searched everywhere and haven't found a suitable solution/conclusion.

Lets assume my index has only one attribute `description` which is of type `text`.

Lets say I want to search `brown dog`. I am interested in results like:

- `the brown dog`
- `the dog is brown`

But I want to discard results with a large value like:

- `the brown dog and the lazy cat`
- `the brown dog jumps over the fence`

In summary, I am only interested in results that are as close as possible to my search text.

Is there a way or a type of query that would allow me to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance! Please feel free to let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about removing hits where the searched field contains "to many" token which does not belong to the query.

Possible in your case it would be enough to set a threshold for the query ([min-score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-min-score)), because the doc.length (aka fieldLen) is part of the calculation of BM25 and [TF-IDF](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-min-score

For sure you can use a [script-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html#query-dsl-script-query) to filter with doc.length.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Karsten. I really appreciate it. I tried to go with the "threshold" approach that you suggested, but it is not trivial for me to determine how to choose the min threshold since the formula to compute the score depend on other terms as well. Do you have any guidance for me here?

I also didn't want to get too fancy and change the scoring behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... There is no a specific way to handle this since what you want exactly can't be do it. The closest thing that you can do is to play with querys and make a good one to get a great score when searching.

https://www.compose.com/articles/elasticsearch-query-time-strategies-and-techniques-for-relevance-part-i/

Read this and I hope you get a better understanding. Feel free to ask me if you are in troubles!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to match tokens exactly(ignoring stop words), you can try below.
I am using stop word filter to remove stopwords(the, is etc.) and token_count data type to store count of remaining tokens. Documents can be queried like:- "search_text": "brown dog" and token length=2.

Mapping:

```
PUT testindex6
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "stop_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase",
          "filter": [
            "english_stop"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "search_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "stop_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "length": {
            "type": "token_count",
            "enable_position_increments":false,
            "analyzer": "stop_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QQ_ADm0BnGA1T2ysD5Hr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "search_text" : "the dog is brown"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Qg_ADm0BnGA1T2ys4JH7",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "search_text" : "the brown dog"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Qw_BDm0BnGA1T2ysUJFH",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "search_text" : "the brown dog and the lazy cat"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET testindex6/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "search_text": "brown dog"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "search_text.length": {
              "value": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "testindex6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QQ_ADm0BnGA1T2ysD5Hr",
        "_score" : 1.2974876,
        "_source" : {
          "search_text" : "the dog is brown"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Qg_ADm0BnGA1T2ys4JH7",
        "_score" : 1.2974876,
        "_source" : {
          "search_text" : "the brown dog"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the fact that you took your time to present a workable solution. I learned about the token_count type with your answer. I upvoted it but since I am new it will not show until I have more reputation.